# Iterate ove directories and perform tasks within each directory

Tags: unix

I hope someone can help me with a bash script that does the following:

1. Iterate over all directories in a path
2. In each directory a) rename a file with name starting with 'jpt' to the directory name, b) move the renamed file to parent directory, c) and then delete the directory.

So, basically I have some folders which have a file starting with 'jpt'. The file name is same in all the folders. I want to replace the folders with the files. Renaming of the files is to make them different.

thank you in advance!

Krishna

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that does what I understand :

```
#!/bin/dash

set -e

mvJtp() {
  local fromDir="$1"
  local f
  for f in "$fromDir"/*
  do if [ -d "$f" ]
     then mvJtp "$f"
     elif [ -f "$f" ]
     then case "$f" in
          "$fromDir"/jpt*) 
              mv -n "$f" "$fromDir".tmp
              rmdir "$fromDir"
              mv -n "$fromDir".tmp "$fromDir"
              return 0
           ;;
          esac
     fi
  done
}

mvJtp jptSrc
```